# 'ENVIRONMENT' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I'm trying to use the quickstart and I keep getting this error when I run npm start.

> 'ENVIRONMENT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Can someone help me I'm doing the authentication quickstart.

Comment: we've [updated the Consumer API OIDC Example](https://github.com/Banno/consumer-api-openid-connect-example/pull/37) and related [Authentication (Node.js Example) quickstart](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/quickstarts/authentication/) to make this easier on Windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before and is a duplicate of [Beginner Working Through Authentication (Node.js example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74817653/beginner-working-through-authentication-node-js-example/74827415).

There are some options listed as comments as well as a general answer for Windows users.